# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when using string.split

Tags: java, regex, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

This problem has kept me frustrated for a few days now.  I am using string split to find the second half of a string.  Here is my code:

```
   String pieces[] = piece.split(before[x]);
   piece = piece.split(before[x])[1];
```

In debug mode i have determined that `piece =`

```
<area shape="circle" coords="329,152,13" href="#g35" alt="" onmouseover="return overlib\('&lt;b>Southeast False Creek&lt;/b>&lt;br>215 West 1st Avenue' , SNAPX, 20, SNAPY, 20\);" onmouseout="return nd\(\);"/>
```

and `before[x] =`

```
<area shape="circle" coords="329,152,13" href="#g35" alt="" onmouseover="return overlib\('&lt;b>
```

For some reason I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception with `split` saying an index of one is invalid.  I dont know why this is happening so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What I can get out of your code wont compile. Would you be able to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) please? By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: I tried to recreate what you've given and the value of `pieces` (by the way, that should be `String[] peices`, not `String pieces[]`) is an empty array of Strings. This means nothing was able to be split by the before[x] you've given, which makes sense. Are you trying to just get everything after the `before[x]`? If that's the case, a `substring` call would be better for you.

Comment: `String pieces[]` is the same as `String[] pieces`.

Comment: Try printing `pieces[]` array to know if you have actually successfully performed the split.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the second half of the string useing `piece.split(before[x])[1]` and its throwing an exception, then obviously it means that your string array `piece.split(before[x])` does not have a second element. What you should do is try using `piece.split(Pattern.quote(before[x]))` and then check the number of strings in the array.
If its more than 1 then you can get the 2nd half of the string using `piece.split(Pattern.quote(before[x]))[1]`.

Read this for more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

String.split use regular expression to split String into pieces. "before[x]" contains regular special characters (i.e. "\"), so you need to escape these special characters. 
refer http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for special character lists